# OpenShift: upload file to server

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web-applications, file-upload, openshift

This OpenShift webapp uses Tomcat7 and sevlets.
Upload File Path from servlet is:

```
String uploadFilePath = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR")+"uploads/";
```

> /var/lib/openshift/53d4da604382ecdd4f000005/app-root/data/uploads/

How to find this file on the server?

> http://webapplication.rhcloud.com/uploads/4567.JPG
>
> http://webapplication.rhcloud.com/var/lib/openshift/53d4da604382ecdd4f000005/app-root/data/uploads/4567.JPG

but response is: The requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR is not publicly available by default.  Try looking through this forum post that talks about how to upload/view files using java on OpenShift: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift

Comment: This doesn't go anywhere but https://developers.openshift.com/. Please post another link. Thanks for your original answer.